# docker app in amazon ec2 This site can’t provide a secure connection

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2

When I am trying to run the application (https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/get-started/part2/#run-the-app) on an Amazon EC2 instance, I get an an error message "This site can’t provide a secure connection".

I have done the following:

1. Amazon Ec2 instance: Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03.0 (HVM), SSD Volume Type
2. Updated INBOUND security group for the following:

   - https
   - All traffic
   - Custom TCP (Port Range 4000)
3. Did the build and ran the docker - `docker run -p 4000:80 friendlyhello`
4. `curl http://localhost:4000` - gives the response, however when I try to access using the browser and the public IP for the ec2 instance (example https://18.224.172.210:4000), I get the error:

> This site can’t provide a secure connection 18.224.172.210 sent an
>   invalid response.
>
> ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Comment: There seems to be an issue with the SSL certificate. Where did you get them? Have you even installed it on the HTTP server? Have you registered your IP's domain name and put the correct domain name in the certificate while registering? (As far as I know, certificates won't let you put IP address for CNAME). Here's for a better understanding of certificates: [Understaning SSL Certificates](https://crackerscreed.org/understanding-ssl-certificates/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your app doesn't serve https - it's accessible under http: [http://18.224.172.210:4000/]

If you want to have https you should start some software (like a loadbalancer) which will terminate https traffic or setup https in your docker image.